# How can I fix this Apache server situation?

Tags: apache

I've been working on a huge upgrade of several websites for several months. It includes upgrading to PDO database connections and modifying Apache so that people who arrive on links pointing to mysite/World/New_York will be redirected to mysite/world/new-york.

Unfortunately, publishing it has been an endless series of disasters. All my websites are crashed, and pages load extremely slowly. It takes forever to publish files online, and sometimes I can't put anything online at all.

So I was happy to get this notice from my webhost; at least I have some clue about what's going on. Can anyone explain to me what it means and what I have to do to fix it?

If there's no solution, do you think I might fix it by simply deleting all my websites (about two dozen of them) entirely, then just publishing them back online slowly, one at a time?

```
IT appears your own server IP is making GET requests to Apache, causing excessive loading and causing service failures. On today's date, your IP made almost 6,000 connections to Apache:<br><br>

[root@host ~]# grep 64.91.229.106 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mysite.org | wc -l 5924 [root@host ~]#<br><br>

These were all the same request:<br><br>

64.91.229.106 - - [12/Apr/2014:08:10:10 -0400] "GET /404.php HTTP/1.0" 200 14294 "-" "-"<br><br>

And that made up the total of requests:<br><br>

[root@host ~]# grep 64.91.229.106 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mysite.org | grep "GET /404.php HTTP/1.0" | wc -l 5924 [root@host ~]#<br><br>

I'd suggest seeking out the assistance of a developer to see where the source of these requests lie, as they are what have been loading down your server today. Let us know if you have any questions.
```

Comment: David, your question is quite hard to answer w/o exact knowledge of how the web applications are organized, what exactly is going on, what are the bottlenecks and what tradeoffs can be. W/o this knowledge all advices would be just, well, "best wishes" w/o any practical meaning. I would suggest you to hire a skilled developer or system administrator to carefully study the situation, perform tests and create a roadmap, what can be changed and how this could improve the situation.

Comment: I think you're right. I've had enough experience with Apache to know it's pretty much a lost cause. I think I'm going to ask my webhost to just pull the plug and delete all my sites so I can start fresh. Thx.

Comment: Update: Unbelievably, I solved this problem myself! When my websites crashed, I was in a hurry to get custom 404 error pages on all of them. So I created ONE custom error page on mysite1 and used file_get_contents to display its contents on files named 404.php on my satellite sites. So I deleted all the fake 404 error pages, and that seemed to fix the problem. Whew. ;)

Comment: Ah, Ok. BTW are you sure that you need PHP or other "dynamic solution" just to show "Sorry, fellow, the page is not here right now"? Usually heavy loaded sites serve statically everything they can (that is everything that can be treated as a static content by their business logic).

Comment: For me dead URL's show nothing except a lame error message, like "No Content," or something like that. The only way I can have a decent 404 error message is to create a special file.

Comment: Well, can you create a static HTML file and then configure apache to display this file on 404 error instead of the default? Use [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errordocument) and serving this static file won't trigger PHP.

Comment: Usually sites with high volume traffic are split into static and dynamic parts with as much static content as possible. Static content is served w/o any PHP or other programming solution at all. Also you may consider use [nginx](http://nginx.org) or [lighttpd](http://lighttpd.net) to serve static content, they're pretty good in that area, much better than Apache.